# source a file in .zshrc does not find the file

Tags: macos, zsh, macos-catalina

I'm using zsh on Catalina and I have some problems with sourcing (dunno if that's the correct term) a file in my .zshrc file that has a white space in the path. 
Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to have my personal zsh settings in iCloud so that it syncs between all my computers. There is a white space in the path to my iCloud directory that I can't change.

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/
```

Escaping the wihte space does not work when I try it.

```
file='~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/file.sh'
source $file
```

Results in:

```
.zshrc:source:29: no such file or directory: ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/file.sh
```

It works fine when I manually do:

```
source ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/file.sh
```

Any ideas on how to solve this or I'm I back at manually load my files?

Comment: What about using double-quotes and `$HOME` as in `file="$HOME/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/file.sh"`?

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: And you changed the single quotes to double quotes?  You shouldn't get *exactly* the same error...

Comment: I changed from ' to " and get the same error save the change in path,
.zshrc:source:29: no such file or directory: /Users/myAccount//Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/file.sh

Comment: OK get rid of the `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are ruining your day, and the excaped space doesn't make much sense either, because you are quoting the whole stuff anyway:

```
file='~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/file.sh'
```

This means that you need a directory with the name `~`.

You could write it as

```
file=~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/file.sh
```

which would substitute the tilde by your home directory. I personally would use double quotes and write it as:

```
file="$HOME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/file.sh"
```